# retrieve the fields we are interested in and write to a result file the fields + count result using scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter

I need to import a CSV file that contains several fields, I must later loop on some fields that interest us to recover the data contained in it.

In the file there is a field named query that contains SQL queries that must be executed and store in another CSV file that will contain the fields to retrieve as well as the results of each query.

Below is my code so far:

```
// step1:read the file
val table_requete = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter", ";").load("/user/swychowski/ClientAnlytics_Controle/00_Params/filtre.csv")
req.registerTempTable("req")
// step2:read the file
```

However, I dont know how to loop and store on another file at the same time.

Comment: Can you add some input and output that you want ?

Comment: what do you mean by add some input and output?

Comment: If you add sample of csv, query file and output it would be easy to help.

Comment: this the input file
controled tab;USD_ID;NCA_ID;CONTROLE_ID;Criteria;query;Actif;Prometheus;OK 
AGG_CONTACT;USD-5;NCA-15;1;nbr_visits_L3Y = 0  for prospect ;select  count(*) from agg_contact where nbr_visits_l3y <> 0 and  typology_id='07';1;;
AGG_HIERARCHIE_MAGASIN;USD-11;NCA-23;1;nbr_client_ytm is not null ;select count(*) from  agg_hie_magasin where nbr_client_ytm is null;1;;

Comment: for the output file i only want the fields ( controled tab;USD_ID;NCA_ID;CONTROLE_ID;result_query)

Comment: so where should this query be executed? RDBMS or Spark/Hive?

Comment: the query is executed  on hive database

Comment: OK I see two more questions, are the queries similar to this one `select count() from agg_contact where nbr_visits_l3y <> 0 and typology_id='07';`? And what is the execution engine of Hive (might be Spark or Hadoop MapReduce)?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis yes the queries are similar to that one, the execution engine is Spark